# Structure breadcrumbs only going 2 levels deep

Tags: structure, eeharbor

I'm using Structure for lots of stuff: title, nav, and breadcrumbs. Title and nav are working, but breadcrumbs only goes 2 levels deep. If I'm a page further down than that, {exp:structure:breadcrumb} produces no output. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

EDIT: Jace from EEHarbor just told me this is a bug that they are working on. Will post an update when this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the other Structure tags (titletrail, nav) take entry_id as a parameter, but it doesn't work with breadcrumb. I added code (taken from those functions) to do this, and it's working now.

Specifically, in user/addons/structure/mod.structure.php, under public function breadcrumb(), adding this in the "// get current entry id" block:

```
$entry_id = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('entry_id', array_search($uri, $site_pages['uris']));
```